# How do I force all traffic through VPN

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, firewall, openvpn

I am using Debian 8, with openvpn, I am able to connect to the vpn but traffic (ping google.com) isn't working (ping: unknown host google.com). Ontop of that I'd like to add an ip table to the firewall to force all incoming and outgoing connections through tun0 (vpn). The local ip for the vpn is 10.9.8.xxx and the external ip is a 173.43.133.xxx. How would I fix the first problem and create the ip to force this?

Thanks --Mike

Comment: You can’t select to receive incoming connections on a different interface. Not without telling the source of the connection to connect differently.

Comment: Is there anyway to deny incoming connections from other interfaces besides tun0?

Comment: Sure, but what would that even accomplish? Unless you’re directly connected to a network you don’t control, it’s pointless.

Comment: Also, please provide your OpenVPN server and client config.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the answer you want, but [BitMask](https://bitmask.net/), based on OpenVPN and part of the [LEAP Encryption Project](https://leap.se/), handles [all of this](https://bitmask.net/en/features) and adds more security besides.  The providers are [listed here](https://bitmask.net/en#providers).  They include RiseUp and Calyx.  If you're really worried about security, that's what I'd go with.