# How to avoid integrated KDE vpn to redirect all traffic through the VPN?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, kde

I just setup a VPN server with OpenVPN. It seems to work so far.

I created a client configuration and keys on my Debian/KDE computer and when I start the VPN client through command-line:

```
sudo openvpn --config ~/client.ovpn
```

The VPN connects and I can ping VPN devices and Internet:

```
ping 10.8.x.x #works
ping example.com #works, because not redirected through the VPN
```

After, I am configuring the VPN client through the "Configure Network connections" by "Add new connection" and then "Import VPN connection"

This connects correctly, and I can ping VPN local devices, but I can't reach Internet because all traffic attempt to go through the VPN

```
ping 10.8.x.x #Works
ping example.com #Does not works -> trying to go through the VPN
```

Due to this, I suspect the KDE VPN management to add some redirecting rule. But I could not find how to avoid it.I am looking for some "Use this connection only for resources on its network" or similar configuration.

The client configuration is:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <VPN-SERVER-IP> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
tls-auth ta.key 1
```

### Question

**How to avoid the KDE VPN GUI to redirect all internet through the VPN?**

---

Related question that for some reason did not answered:

[How do I force all traffic through VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1088151/how-do-i-force-all-traffic-through-vpn)
[OpenVPN: Routing all client traffic through the VPN - Do non-Windows clients require some extra server-side scripting?](https://superuser.com/questions/1163301/openvpn-routing-all-client-traffic-through-the-vpn-do-non-windows-clients-req)

---

Image of KDE VPN gui:
[image: KDE VPN gui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Network Manager's System Settings window (the gray window in the background of your screenshot above) open the IPv4 tab, click on the command button "Routes..." and select "**Use only for resources on this connection**", confirm and apply.